# How to specify an in buffer archive file name for emacs org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to specify in an .org file, the filename of its archive file.

Something like myarchivefile.org

I would like the archive file to be in the same directory as my .org file.

The page: 16.7 Summary of In-Buffer Settings

https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html

has:

‘#+ARCHIVE: %s_done’

as an example. Even though this is not what I want, I put this code in my .org file (without quotation marks) and it gave an error - invalid location.

Plus this page does not explain what %s_done means.

I have searched and searched and found nothing helpful. I have tried different things to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set archive location globally customizing variable `org-archive-location` or locally, as in the manual page you referred to. However, the example from manual is actually not correct (already fixed). You should use ‘#+ARCHIVE: %s_done::’.

The information about format used to set archive location is described in `org-archive-location` variable docstring. You can find it using `<F1> v org-archive-location <RET>` or from menu Help->Describe->Describe variable... `org-archive-location <RET>`. In general, you can find detailed information about any Emacs variable using the described procedure.

Comment: Hi yantar92 - Thanks very much for your help - your answer helped me determine that all I need to do is eg #+ARCHIVE: ArchiveFile.org::

Comment: If your question is answered to your satisfaction, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Thanks NickD also for answering my other question. I am new to stack and did not realize I should checkmark the answer - I have done so now.